Static pressure vs ambient pressure
If in a real scenario, a flat surface with a flush perpendicular closed duct of small diameter is exposed to a tangential fluid flow(laminar and naturally with the presence of boundary layer effect), does the airflow induce a lower than ambient pressure (measured near the surface outside of the duct inlet) in the duct? And if not why?

please provide a sketch.
